# binomial theorem expansion quick question

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm looking at a proof online to a theorem and some of the steps to the theorem are as follows:

let $ x = y+1$ then
$$x^p-1 = (y+1)^p -1 = y^p + \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {p \choose k} y^k$$
$$\iff \frac{x^p-1}{x-1} = \frac{(y+1)^p-1}{y} = y^{p-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{p-2}{p \choose k}y^{k-1}$$ I am wondering how the $p-1$ in the sum went to $p-2$?

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me. Clearly the expression above is being divided by $y$. And that is accounted for in the exponent, so there's no reason for the summation to stop at $p-2$.

Comment: There must be a typo.  The division by $y$ was considered in the exponent of the $y^k$ terms as they became $y^{k-1}$. The upper limit should not have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $p-1$ in summation.